# Next Button with simple js works in chrome, opera but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, mozilla

I have next and previous button in step form in css and js.

Button works flawlessly in chrome and opera.

Due to Unknown reason it doesn't works in Mozilla Firefox.

> The code of Button:

```html
<div style="overflow:auto;">
  <div style="float:right;">
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The live url of the form is [HERE](https://dog.nepromedia.com/booking/)

I Used this [example code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps) to build my form.

I don't why the next button isn't working though I used the exact format in the example.

The next button seems to be working in example after the details are entered but not in my code.

> Here is my Full HTML Code used from the above example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
  #regForm {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 100px auto;
    font-family: Raleway;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 300px;
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  input {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  }
  /* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
  
  input.invalid {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
  }
  /* Hide all steps by default: */
  
  .tab {
    display: none;
  }
  
  button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  
  #prevBtn {
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
  }
  /* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
  
  .step {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  
  .step.active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
  
  .step.finish {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab  w3-margin-bottom">
    <h3>Pick a Service:</h3>
    <form id="reservationForm" method="POST" action="/booking/" onsubmit="return false">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <div class="w3-row">
          <div class="w3-bar">
            <button type="button" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-black " style="width:100%" id="service1" onclick="onServicesClicked(event, 'service1');">
                                    <i class="fa fa-moon-o w3-text-cyan"></i>
                                    <br>
                                    <span><strong>Dog Boarding</strong></span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span><small>Overnight Stay</small></span>
                                </button>


            <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" value="dog-boarding">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-card w3-container w3-margin-top">
          <div class="w3-row-padding">
            <div class="w3-quarter">
              <p>
                <label><b>When would you like to Dropoff</b></label>
                <input id="start_date" class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom hasDatepicker" type="text" name="start_date" required="" onchange="setStartDate(this)" min="2019-06-28">
              </p>
            </div>

            <div class="w3-quarter">
              <p>
                <label><b>At what time</b></label>
                <select id="start_time" class="w3-input w3-select w3-border" name="start_time" style=" height:38px;" onchange="checkStartWorkingHour(this)">
                  <option value="7:00 AM">7:00 AM</option>
                  <option value="7:30 AM">7:30 AM</option>
                  <option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
                  <option value="8:30 AM">8:30 AM</option>
                  <option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option>
                  <option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
                  <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
                  <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
                  <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
                  <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
                  <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="6:00 PM">6:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="6:30 PM">6:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="7:00 PM">7:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="7:30 PM">7:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="8:00 PM">8:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="8:30 PM">8:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="9:00 PM">9:00 PM</option>
                  <option value="9:30 PM">9:30 PM</option>
                  <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
                </select>
              </p>
            </div>

            <div id="service1_div" style="display: block;">
              <div class="w3-quarter">
                <p>
                  <label><b>When would you like to Pickup</b></label>
                  <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom hasDatepicker" type="text" name="end_date" onchange="setEndDate(this)" id="end_date" min="2019-06-28">
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="w3-quarter">
                <p>
                  <label><b>At what time</b></label>
                  <select id="end_time1" class="w3-input w3-select w3-border" name="end_time1" style=" height:38px;" onchange="checkEndWorkingHour(this)">
                    <option value="7:00 AM">7:00 AM</option>
                    <option value="7:30 AM">7:30 AM</option>
                    <option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
                    <option value="8:30 AM">8:30 AM</option>
                    <option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option>
                    <option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
                    <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
                    <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
                    <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
                    <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
                    <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="6:00 PM">6:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="6:30 PM">6:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="7:00 PM">7:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="7:30 PM">7:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="8:00 PM">8:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="8:30 PM">8:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="9:00 PM">9:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="9:30 PM">9:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
                  </select>
                </p>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div id="service2_div" style="display: none;">
              <div class="w3-third">
                <p>
                  <label><b>Time you will Pickup your dogs?</b></label>
                  <select id="end_time2" class="w3-input w3-select w3-border" name="end_time2" style=" height:38px;" onchange="checkStartWorkingHour(this)">
                    <option value="7:00 AM">7:00 AM</option>
                    <option value="7:30 AM">7:30 AM</option>
                    <option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
                    <option value="8:30 AM">8:30 AM</option>
                    <option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option>
                    <option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
                    <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
                    <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
                    <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
                    <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
                    <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="6:00 PM">6:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="6:30 PM">6:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="7:00 PM">7:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="7:30 PM">7:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="8:00 PM">8:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="8:30 PM">8:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="9:00 PM">9:00 PM</option>
                    <option value="9:30 PM">9:30 PM</option>
                    <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
                  </select>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="service34_div" style="display: none;">
              <div class="w3-third">
                <p>
                  <label><b>Where should I Pickup your dog(s)?</b></label>
                  <input class="w3-input" type="text" name="start_address1" id="start_address1" value="" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">
                </p>

              </div>
              <div class="w3-third">
                <p>
                  <label><b>Any special instructions?</b></label>
                  <textarea class="w3-input w3-select w3-border" id="d_walk_notes" name="d_walk_notes" rows="5" cols="15" placeholder="How do I get in the house? Will you be home? Etc...">                                            </textarea>

                </p>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div id="service12_div" class="w3-card-4 w3-container w3-margin-top" style="display: block;">
          <div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin-bottom">
            <div class="w3-half">
              <p>
                <label><b>Need ME to Pickup your dogs?</b></label>
              </p>
              <input class="w3-radio w3-input" type="radio" name="dog_pickup" value="1" onclick="onRadioClicked('pickup_yes')">
              <label>Yes</label>
              <input class="w3-radio w3-input" type="radio" name="dog_pickup" value="0" checked="" onclick="onRadioClicked('pickup_no')">
              <label>No</label>
              <div id="dog_pickup_yes_div" style="display: none;">
                <label><b>Enter Pickup Address:</b></label>
                <input class="w3-input" type="text" name="start_address2" id="start_address2" value="" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-half">
              <p>
                <label><b>Need ME to Dropoff your dogs?</b></label>
              </p>
              <input class="w3-radio w3-input" type="radio" name="dog_dropoff" value="1" onclick="onRadioClicked('drop_yes')">
              <label>Yes</label>
              <input class="w3-radio w3-input" type="radio" name="dog_dropoff" value="0" checked="" onclick="onRadioClicked('drop_no')">
              <label>No</label>

              <div id="dog_dropoff_yes_div" style="display: none;">
                <label><b>Enter Dropoff Address:</b></label>
                <input class="w3-input" type="text" name="end_address" id="end_address" value="" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="tab  w3-margin-bottom">
    <h3>Dogs Information:</h3>
    <form id="dogsForm" method="POST" action="/booking/" onsubmit="return false">

      <div class="w3-container">

        <div id="" class="w3-row">
          <div class="w3-row-padding">
            <div class="w3-quarter">
              <p>
                <label><b>Name</b></label>
                <input id="dog_name" class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom" type="text" name="dog_name">
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-quarter">
              <p>
                <label><b>Age</b></label>
                <input id="dog_age" class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom" type="number" name="dog_age" style="height:38px">
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-quarter">
              <p>
                <label><b>Size in (LBS)</b></label>
                <select id="dog_size" class="w3-input w3-select w3-border" name="dog_size" style=" height:38px;">
                  <option value="small">Small (0-40)</option>
                  <option value="large">Large (40+)</option>
                </select>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-quarter">
              <p>
                <label><b>&nbsp;</b></label>
                <button class="w3-input w3-bar-item w3-button w3-small w3-blue" style="width:50%" id="dog6" onclick="addRowToTable(event);">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus w3-margin-right"></i>
                                            <span><strong>Add</strong></span>
                                        </button>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="" class="w3-row">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="dog_table" class="wp-list-table tables">
              <tbody>
                <tr class="w3-black">
                  <th class="manage-column ss-list-width">Name</th>
                  <th class="manage-column ss-list-width">Age</th>
                  <th class="manage-column ss-list-width">Size</th>
                  <th class="w3-right-align">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>



  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)" style="display: none;">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
  <script>
    var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

    function showTab(n) {
      // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
      x[n].style.display = "block";
      //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
      if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
      }
      if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
      }
      //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
      fixStepIndicator(n)
    }

    function nextPrev(n) {
      // This function will figure out which tab to display
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
      // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
      if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
      // Hide the current tab:
      x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
      // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
      currentTab = currentTab + n;
      // if you have reached the end of the form...
      if (currentTab >= x.length) {
        // ... the form gets submitted:
        document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
        return false;
      }
      // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
      showTab(currentTab);
    }

    function validateForm() {
      // This function deals with validation of the form fields
      var x, y, i, valid = true;
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
      y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
      // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
      for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        // If a field is empty...
        if (y[i].value == "") {
          // add an "invalid" class to the field:
          y[i].className += " invalid";
          // and set the current valid status to false
          valid = false;
        }
      }
      // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
      if (valid) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
      }
      return valid; // return the valid status
    }

    function fixStepIndicator(n) {
      // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
      var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
      x[n].className += " active";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works in FF 67.0.4 (64-bit) on Linux. Can you provide more details on your test case?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I have windows. Firefox Version 67.0.4 (64-bit)

Comment: It also works for me on Windows (same version). What exactly doesn't work? Provide more detail on what you are expecting. The button turns gray because some stuff hasn't been filled, just like on Chrome. Perhaps you should restart FF !? Or the system?

Comment: Try Filling in a few details and then clicking next. Actually, it is a step form, when I click next the form should load the next step and the previous button should appear as well. Maybe you can check it on chrome for exact process.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Try Filling in a few details and then clicking next. Try this on both chrome and firefox and you will know what I am trying to elaborate

Comment: Maybe you should provide the exact steps to reproduce the issue!? Also note your question is *off-topic* on SO. Because once you get an answer, you'll change the example, so it will no longer be useful for anyone with a similar issue, and that's the **main reason** why anyone would provide an answer. Consider adding a [mcve] to the question itself, so it will remain relevant even after it has been answered.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu here is the form i used https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps . For more Please compare the HTML of my code and the example.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will not submit a form if  the form does not contain a submit button - even if the submit is initiated through code.